# Concavity intervals

Tags: problem-solving

My second derivative is

$$\frac{(250-64 x^3)}{(3 x (-125+8 x^3))^\frac{5}{3}}
$$
I know that function is undefined if $x = 0$ and $x=5/2$.
What would be concavity intervals? Why not $(-\infty,0)$,$(0,5/2)$ - Increasing
and $(5/2,\infty)$ - decreasing ?

Comment: The numerator also affects the sign. The places where there could be a change in sign, and therefore of concavity, include the cube root of $250/64$.

Comment: ah, yes yes. Even with the extra point 5/(2 2^(2/3)), I'm still not able to solve it

Comment: Increasing (-INF,0)(0,root)
Decreasing (root,5/2),(5/2,INF) Something wrong?
My first derivative was (8x^4-125x)^(-2/3)

Comment: What was the original function?

Comment: I didn't have one. Just a derivative of the function. So, my increasing interval (-inf,0) doesn't seems to work. As well as my decreasing (0,root),(root,5/2),(5/2,inf)

Comment: Here is correct calculation. For $x\lt 0$, top is negative, bottom positive, concave down. For $0\lt x\lt (125/32)^{1/3}$, top negative, bottom negative, concave up. then up to $5/2$ top positive, bottom negative, concave down. After $5/2$, everything positive, concave up. (I had wrong sign before.)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Shame on me for not being able to solve this problem myself.

Comment: Minus signs are a headache. I have trouble with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top is negative up to $x=(125/32)^{1/3}\approx 1.575$. The bottom is positive for $x\lt 0$, negative for $0\lt x\lt 5/2$, and positive for $x\gt 5/2$.

Thus for $x\lt 0$, the second derivative is negative, and therefore the first derivative is decreasing, the graph is concave down.

From $0$ to $(125/32)^{1/3}$, the top is still negative. The bottom is negative, so the ratio is positive, the graph of our function is concave up (some people say convex).

From $(125)^{1/3}$, for similar reasons the graph is concave down.

Finally, past $5/2$, the curve is concave up.